# Add events by css class name javafx

Tags: java, css, javafx, fxml, dashboard

Here I create a css class and add them to 10 labels. (Buttons in dashboard. As Mouse over events are same, same class is used)
Now I want to change the button style after it is pressed. And that mouse over effect must be removed.

How can I do this?

Comment: Here is a solution. /s Show your code.

Comment: So you want some effect like the links in a webbrowser becoming purple after visiting them... Is that correct?

Comment: No. Not that exactly. After click button, and load the panel, that button must be selected. I need to apply events, after selecting any node with same class

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your CSS currently looks like this:

```
.mybutton
{
    /*some styles*/
}
.mybutton:hover
{
    /*some styles*/
}
```

Change it to:

```
.mybutton
{
    /*some styles*/
}
.mybutton.unpressed:hover
{
    /*some styles*/
}
```

Then add the class 'unpressed' to all buttons, and remove it when the button is pressed:

```
myButton.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> 
     myButton.getStyleClass().remove("unpressed");
);
```

Comment: By this method, I have to write this for all the buttons seperately. I need to get, when .mybutton -(name of the css)- is pressed, change its css only.

Comment: I don't know what you mean.

Comment: All the buttons have same css style class name (.mybutton). When pressed anything (any button) that have .mybutton css, I need to start actions.

Comment: Yep. That's what I assumed. That's not a problem.

Comment: I need to start action when anything clicked with that same css style name